# Mod-rewrite on server

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When I contact to my host provider, I have informed  that the mod-rewrite is already enabled in the server. I have inserted the following code in the .htaccess file, which works well in local server but not in server

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f  
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^filename1/name1/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.html$ filename2.php?id=$2
RewriteRule ^filename1/name2/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.html$ filename3.php?id=$2
RewriteRule ^filename1/name3/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.html$ filename4.php?id=$2
RewriteRule ^filename1/name4/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.html$ filename5.php?id=$2
```

Comment: So what doesn't work? What's in the error logs? What error are you getting in your browser? Is anything happening at all?

Comment: The redirection doesn`t work at all and not getting any error logs.This site files are not in the root folder,it is pointed from the sub directory.

Comment: If the path to access these requests are different than on your local server, then the same rules won't work.

Comment: Check if htaccess is enabled by typing some garbage into the file. If htaccess is enabled, you should get a 500 error. Also try adding `RewriteBase /folder/htacces/is/in`

Comment: I have checked by adding "HMMMMM" in the htaccess and got 500 error, also used RewriteBase /foldername